# How can I make a combolist from a json created by a query Select/where in php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to make a DropDownlist, selecting an id, selecting option, using a function receiving the value, but it doesn't return in the combo.

This is the function that receives the id value

```
function findUser(id_company){
            $.getJSON('../loadUsers.php', { iduser: id_company }, function (data) {
                $("#comboUser").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#comboUser").empty();
                $("#comboUser").append("<option value=''>" + "Select" + "</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    alert(optionData.id);
                    $("#comboUser").append("<option value='" + optionData.id + "'>" + optionData.name + "</option>");
                });

            });
```

And this is the loadUsers.php

```
<?php

include('../config.php');

$arrayUsers = [];
$i = 0;
$idcompany = $_POST["id_company"];

echo($idempresa);


$users = mysql_query("SELECT * from hospital_".$_SESSION['template'].".users where id_company = ".$idcompany." order by name");


while($compuser = mysql_fetch_array($users, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $arrayUser[$i] = $compuser;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode(array($arrayUser));

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what happens instead?

Comment: `..loadUsers.php`? Maybe `../loadUsers.php` or some other path?

Comment: Check in the Console of developer tools, I think the jquery can't make ajax call to your php script, like what @u_mulder said

Comment: It just shows "Undefined" in the Select Box. It looks like the phpf file is creating the json results, but is not returning the values in the Combo.

Comment: Sorry, @u_mulder. I forgot to type the "/" in my code.

Comment: You've got another typo.  echo json_encode(array($arrayUsers)); should be echo json_encode(array($arrayUser));